# Limits related $f(g(x))$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(g(x))=L$ provided that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to b} g(x)=a$ and that $g(x)\neq a$ for a deleted neighborhood of $b$.

I think following steps are correct

$$\lim _{x\to a}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=f\left(\lim _{x\to a}\left(x\right)\right)=f\left(a\right)=f\left(\lim _{x\to b}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right)$$

But I cannot match them and reach the answer.

Comment: All you had to do was insert dollar signs $$ around the text.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you need to prove the above statement?

Comment: yes I need to prove it